# Как сделать плавной появление блока?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после загрузки html кода в блок после ajax запроса, блок .favorite-products плавно выезжал справа?

сейчас он плавно появляется и все

```js
$('.favorite-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/favorites/get',
      success: function (response) {
        $('.toggle-dialog-container').html(response);
        $('.toggle-dialog').fadeIn();
        $('.favorite-products').animate({
          right : "0"
        });
        
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        toast.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: jqXHR.responseJSON.message
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.favorite-btn{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.toggle-dialog{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9991;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.toggle-dialog-background{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.favorite-products{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 295px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
}
.toggle-dialog-container {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="favorite-btn"></div>
<div class="toggle-dialog">
  <div class="toggle-dialog-background"></div>
  <div class="toggle-dialog-container">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так или как?

```js
$('.favorite-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/favorites/get',
      success: function (response) {
        $('.toggle-dialog-container').html(response);
        $('.toggle-dialog').fadeIn();
        $('.favorite-products').animate({
          right : "0"
        });
        
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: jqXHR.responseJSON,
          showClass: {
            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInRight'
          },
          hideClass: {
            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutLeft'
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.favorite-btn{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.toggle-dialog{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9991;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.toggle-dialog-background{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.favorite-products{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 295px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
}
.toggle-dialog-container {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
<div class="favorite-btn">Click here</div>
<div class="toggle-dialog">
  <div class="toggle-dialog-background"></div>
  <div class="toggle-dialog-container">
    
  </div>
</div>
```